# iOS project using sqlcipher doesn't build anymore after installing Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl, sqlcipher, libcrypto

I'm developing an application using sqlcipher though i walked through sqlcipher tutorial to install it and everything worked well on simulators and devices using OSX 10.8.5 and Xcode 4.6.
 After installing Xcode 5 the project failed to build with error

> no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/ADeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApplication-hhvsixvmxupohxbrkfwiwevnnupm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libcrypto.a'

I tried to build the project using Xcode 4.6 (which was working well before) but it failed with the same issue.

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it accidently when trying to solve another problem.
The mistake was that the path of "***Header Search Paths***" had an invalid value which is a space where Xcode automatically inserts escape character (backslash) before. After renaming this path component from the finder to a valid name the project is built successfully.